# How to get the current size of my Ubuntu installation?

Tags: 12.10

I've been going through my Ubuntu set up and tweaking all of my configurations and removing unnecessary packages and programs to create my perfect linux desktop.

Is there any way to get the current size of my installation and it's packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect list of how to achieve this could be found for example here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=599424

Comment: When using the list_installed_packages_by_size.sh script (could be in the linked forum), the total size is:

list_installed_packages_by_size.sh 1 | awk 'BEGIN { t=0; } { t+=$1; } END { print t; }'

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to know, how much disk your linux installation uses, you can simply go to a terminal and check the disk usage of your root folders

```
 sudo du -h -s /usr 
 sudo du -h -s /etc
```

and so on. The `-h` option stands for "human readable" and `-s` for "summary".